# Redis Server and Elastic Search Integration

Tags: java, c#, elasticsearch, redis

Not sure if this is asked early (I did not get proper results when searched)

I need to use Elastic search on top of Redis. What is the best possible way?

Comment: @UUIIUI
This question is most towards design/architecture. As both Java and C# folks are using Redis and Elastic Search, I want to listen all the versions to take final decision.

Comment: By "Elastic search on top of Redis" do you mean Redis logs would be collected to Elasticsearch? If so, how does the programming language play a role as you can use just the "ELK" stack? Or do you wish to cache ES queries to Redis to avoid re-running queries multiple times, in which case they don't directly talk to each other?

Comment: @NikoNyrh

I started understanding that point. But can you give me insight on what exactly LogStash will do?
 

I am investigating on  this and I am facing with some doubts on input and output configurations.

Comment: I haven't personally used Logstash or Kibana, just ES. There is tons of material available online, I found a summary blog post at http://www.neteye-blog.com/2014/10/neteye-integration-logstashelasticsearchkibana/

Logstash reads log files, parses them and stores to ES in real time, from Kibana dashboard you can visualize what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate Redis-> **Logstash** -> Elasticsearch, without worry about java or c# coding.  Logstash is a product from elasticsearch that already comes with a redis and elasticsearch plug-in. Then the only thing that you have to worry about is how to stick data into the redis, and how to read from the elastic. For that there are libraries for both coding languages and you should choose the one you have more experience with.

Comment: Thank you for the details. I will investigate on it. By the way, is Logstash is a service(running on ES) or server?

Comment: Is a service, not running on elasticsearch. Is a diferent application. https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash